# Node-Red: Parsing JSON data and converting it into binary.

Tags: node-red

Right off the bat, I'm a total noob so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a breakdown of my issue, here are the nodes as seen on my screenshot:

**INJECT-** 
Self explanitory

**NAME-** 
    return{payload:"=00ECC90AG001XQ01"
    };

**HTTP request get point-**
    msg.url = "http://192.168.63/get_points/"+msg.payload
    msg.method = "GET";
    return msg;

**http request-**
Set to GET.

**JSONpath-**
    $.points[0].st
This is setup to parse the JSON located at http://192.168.63/get_points/=00ECC90AG001XQ01.

The output I get form this is 458886.

I would like to convert this number to Binary.
Then I would like to parse out the -7 digit from that Binary.

I tried using the Binary node (the one disconnected on the screenshot), which is for converting inputs to Binary. I could not get passed the "Pattern" requirement.[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary node is probably not the node you are looking for, it's more for building/parsing complex binary structures.

The simpler way to do this will be a function node with something like the following:

```
var binary = msg.payload.toString(2);
// 6 because it's zero based count
var bit7 = binary.charAt(6);
msg.payload = bit7;
return msg;
```

This will find the 7th char from the left

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! One more question though, I'd first need to convert the 458886 to binary (0b1110000000010000110). Any ideas?

Comment: no, the first line of the function converts the number to binary. `toString(2)` converts the number to a string in base 2 (without the '0b' on the front)

Comment: You're right, whats throwing me is I keep getting numbers from my original 458886 popping up, after it should have been converted to binary, should only be picking up a 1 or 0. This is what I have now and my output is 5, Somewhere along the line I'm losing that conversion to binary: var binary = msg.payload.toString(2); var alarmBit = binary.charAt(binary.length-5); msg.payload = alarmBit; return msg; One more question, if you'd be so great, why isn't the variable stored in just the variable msg, why must it be in msg.payload? Is this just some type of method built into Node-Rd?

Comment: The function is assuming the input is a number, not the string representation of that number